# Body margin issue in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I would like to find a solution for the following behaviour.

If you go to the next link [example page](http://test.sistemas-administrativos-digitales.tk/) and change to the mobile view in the developer tools, you could see that for some of the devices that you can choose the toolbar hide partially on scrolling down. Even the view creates a margin in the right side of the page that can be shown scrolling laterally.

I can not find who is causing the issue. I have checked the sizes of every single div in the page even for hidden div. I don't know if the issue is related with the property fixed in the css.

Here you can see what I mean, the toolbar is hidden when scroll down and if you scroll laterally some small margin appears.

[image]

Comment: unable to replicate this issue. Which device are you trying?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan nexus 5, iphone 5 and iphone 6 for the nexus 5x and iphone 6p the behaviour is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct fix, but the Firefox inspector has a 3D mode that is actually very helpful in finding the offending elements in these cases.

Comment: Interesting, I will try to use it and see if I can find the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it with the following edits:

```
.slick-prev: {left: 0;}
.slick-next: {right: 0;}
```

`.container{padding: 0;}` (inside of "`.main-banner`" one)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still have the issue with the changes.

Comment: I still urge you to do that. Make sure that you reset padding of `.container`. And for the other step, i see that you are not using arrows(button) on slider of "Clients". You can remove them with JS by adding `arrows: false` or, you can edit your css like i wrote you above or, you can add `display: none;` to those both classes(`.slick-prev` and `.slick-next`).